# Redireccions al pasar de HTTP a HTTPS

Tags: .htaccess

Esta semana tengo intención e adquirir una licencia SSL, y me da bastante respeto el hecho de no saber exactamente cuál es el proceso que supone. He preguntado ya a mi proveedor de hosting con quien también tengo contratado el dominio y no me acaba de quedar nada claro el proceso a seguir. Una vez haga el cambio a HTTPS,

¿Tendría que añadir en el fichero `.htaccess` algún código para que todas las URLs que apuntan a HTTP sean redirigidas a HTTPS?

¿Afectaría esto a la indexación de las páginas?

Comment: Si no quieres gastarte un dineral y quieres aprender de verdad como funcionan te recomiendo investigar sobre Let's Encrypt, https://letsencrypt.org/

Comment: 20€ anuales no me parece un dineral. Es la segunda vez que me escribes un comentario similar haciendo referencia a la misma página. Yo no soy programador, suficiente tengo con hacer una página web con código puro como para ponerme a entender cómo funciona el certificado SSL.

Answer (score 0):

Si estás usando Apache como servidor Web deberías tener el `Virtual-Host` o lo que sea que hagas para el HTTPS (que ya se lo montarán la gente del hosting supongo) y añadir una redirección para que cada petición http en tu sitio se vuelva HTTPS. Si estás utilizando algún CMS (o motor de blogs, de ventas, de gestión) deberías configurarlo para que a partir de ese momento genere los enlaces correctos.

En cuanto a lo de la indexación no creo que cause inpacto si tienes un certificado válido.

Comment: Gracias por tu respuesta. Uso Apache para configurar el servidor, tengo varias redirecciones en `.htaccess` para las URLs amigables sobretodo. La preocupación que tengo es que si por ejemplo la URL es http://miweb.com, al pasar a https sería https://miweb.com. Lo que no sé es si todos los enlaces que ha estado indexando se perderían o simplemente con una redirección seguirían siendo funcionales. 

Uso rutas absolutas en el código, con lo que tan sólo tengo que modificar el valor de la variable para pasar de http a https.

Comment: La redirección no debe afectar el indexado, los robots de indexado son lo bastante inteligentes para seguir las redirecciones. En cuanto a posicionamiento ya tendrías que consultar a alguien que sepa más de SEO

Answer (score 0):

Una cosa que tienes que mirar es si es un [certificado comodín](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Certificado_comod%C3%ADn) (o *wildcard*) o no, es decir, si te permite tener varios dominios/subdominios bajo el mismo certificado y qué dominios van a estar incluidos en el certificado SSL.

Por ejemplo, yo tengo un certificado que cubre hasta 5 dominios, entonces para "ahorrar dominios" lo que hago es que sólo incluyo los http://midominio.com pero no los http://www.midominio.com (con el `www.`).

Eso lo consigo poniendo lo siguiente en el .htaccess (tengo midominio.com en la carpeta midominio):

```
Options +FollowSymLinks -MultiViews
# Activar mod_rewrite
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /midominio/

# quitar el www y redirigir a https
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} \s/+midominio/(\S*)\s [NC]
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off [OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\. [NC]
RewriteRule ^ https://midominio.com/%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,NE,L]
```

Sobre si afecta a la indexación de páginas, sí y no. Los motores de búsqueda tendrán indexada tu versión `http://`, pero como tienes puesta una redirección de `http` a `https` tus usuarios no notarán ningún problema, y la próxima vez que se indexe tu sitio web, como le has puesto una redirección permanente (301), el motor de búsqueda indexará la página `https` correctamente.

Comment: Gracias por tu respuesta Alvaro, has comentado una serie de cosas que ni sabía. El certificado que he mirado es de un sólo dominio y no incluye Wildcard, es el más barato de los 4 que se indican en este link: https://raiolanetworks.es/certificados-ssl/. Por otra parte, tengo redireccionada la web para que cuando no tiene www se dirige a la dirección con www. Entiendo que la que tendría que incluir es la que tiene www. No pensaba yo que se trataba de dominios distintos.

Comment: Yo tengo GoDaddy, un certificado que cubre 5 dominios y dos son obligatorios el propio y su www. Si lo que quieres es añadir el www. en lugar de quitarlo, tendrías que cambiar la penúltima fila por algo como esto `RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^[^.]+\.[^.]+$` ([fuente](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12257010/3695983))

Comment: Gracias, veo que en GoDaddy los precios son algo más elevados, imagino que la calidad también. Lo que no entiendo es porqué es obligatorio que indiques el dominio propio y su www. Entiendo que el código que has indicado es para que aunque pongas www.miweb.com (con www), te redireccione al dominio sin www. ¿Sabrías decirme qué hace esta linea concretamente? `RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off [OR]`. Me parece curioso lo del off.

Comment: Esa línea es una condición, sólo se redirecciona al https si la URL no está ya en https.

Comment: Y GoDaddy no es que sea mejor... era más sencillo al principio y con cupones y códigos se pueden pillar muchos descuentos