# Redireccionar de HTTP a HTTPS con htaccess

Tags: php, .htaccess

A ver si algun compañero me saca de dudas.

**Estoy por lanzar una nueva web diseñada con php** y quiero modificar el archivo .htaccess para utilizar el certificado de seguridad SSL.

**He encontrado tantos ejemplos que no se cual utilizar**. Alguien seria tan amable y me podria explicar si es posible detalladamente que significa cada linea de los codigos que muestro a continuacion o para que sirve cada uno.

**Ejemplo 1: Este utiliza (IfModule)**.

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteRule (.*) https://www.example.com/$1 [R=301,L,QSA]
</IfModule>
```

**Ejemplo 2:**

```
# Enviar trafico HTTP a HTTPS
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{ENV:HTTPS} !on [NC]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^tu_dominio\.com$ [OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.tu_dominio\.com$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://tudominio.com/$1 [R=301,L,NE]
```

**Y en algunos casos recomiendan agregar las siguientes lineas, que no se tampoco para que sirven:**

```
SSLOptions + StrictRequire
SSLRequireSSL

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
```

**El que pueda responder mis dudas estare super agradecido con usted.**

Desde ya muchas gracias por su tiempo.

Saludos.

Comment: Posible duplicado de [Redireccions al pasar de HTTP a HTTPS](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/79870/redireccions-al-pasar-de-http-a-https)

Comment: Hola fredyfx, ya habia visto esa pregunta y no me aclaro mis dudas, por eso realice una nueva haber si alguna persona me podria ayudar.

Comment: claro mi estimado, estás en la hermandad de SOes, aquí nos apoyamos entre todos. Buenas vibras lml

Answer (score 2, accepted):

usa este es el mas sencillo y te sacara de apuros.

*PD: En los comentarios te explico para que sirve cada una.*

```
RewriteEngine On

#Redireccionar a https cuando tiene www
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.
RewriteRule .* https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]

#Redireccionar a https con www cuando no tiene https ni www
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\.
RewriteRule .* https://www.tupagina.com%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]

#Redireccionar a www cuando tiene https
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\.
RewriteRule .* https://www.tupagina.com%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]
```

Comment: ok Brian, espero tus comentarios. Saludos.

Comment: @juanpablo en los comentarios del código :P

Comment: Disculpame soy medio nuevo en SO, en donde me dirijo para ver los comentarios. Saludos.

Comment: Disculpame te referias a los comentarios del codigo presentado, buscaba algo ma completo ya que yo necesitaba saber que quiere decir cada linea, de todas formas te agradezco por tu ayuda. Saludos.